# Find length in seconds of mp3 in byte array format without third party code

Tags: c#

I have been searching for an answer to this question, but everything I come across requires something like `NAudio` or `TagLib`.

If I have an mp3 converted into a C# byte array, is there a way to get the length of the file in seconds, but without using third party code.

Comment: See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43208/How-to-get-the-length-duration-of-a-media-File-in).

Answer (score 2):

Count the [frames](http://www.mp3-converter.com/mp3codec/mp3_anatomy.htm) and [multiply by ~38](http://www.mp3-converter.com/mp3codec/frames.htm)